# Monkey patching a module on import

Tags: python, import, monkeypatching

I've got a package structure like this

```
mypackage
 |-- core.py
 |-- device.py
 |-- async.py
 |-- ...
```

The `core.py` defines a `Command` class, which handles the communication with a device.
The communication is synchronous (blocking).

```
#core.py
class Command(object):
    #...
```

The device module defines a device class, which uses the `Command` class to provide an API for a real device, e.g. an oscilloscope.

```
# device.py
class MyDevice(object):
    cmd1 = Command(...)
    cmd2 = Command(...)
```

The async module defines an asyncronous version of `Command`.

```
# async.py
class Command(object):
    # asyncronous command implementation
```

Now what I'd like to to is the following:

```
# Note: There is no real /mypackage/async/device.py file
import mypackage.async.device
dev = mypackage.async.device.MyDevice(...) # uses asyncronous Command implementation
```

There are many classes like `MyDevice`. I don't wan't to rewrite every one of them just to switch the `Command` implementation. That's why I think patching would work quite nice. But it should also be explicit (different import, the user should not know that patching has been done).

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: If you are looking to leave the original import the same, what exactly about this is patching?  How is this not just standard subclassing?

Comment: @Joran Beasley Ok, I reformulated the question, hope this clarifies what I'd like to do.